# Joomla 2.5.6: extention to poll Youtube Channel videos and their comments

Tags: joomla2.5

I searched for Joomla 2.5.6: extention to poll youtube channel videos and their comments but not found if some body knows then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Got them on joomla forum but all are commercial please check if any of these can help you [http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=poll+youtube](http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=poll%20youtube)